# Do Snap packages support private repositories?

Tags: repository, snap, packaging, github, ubuntu-store

https://docs.snapcraft.io/build-snaps/ci-integration

As documented here I am a game developer and have created a game on Unreal Engine and I have put my game package on git in a private repository. Can I use this to deploy the package on to the Ubuntu store? Or do I need to make it public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can register private snaps. When you are on the page for [registering snaps](https://dashboard.snapcraft.io/register-snap/) there is a tick to mark a snap as private or not.

[Check image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0uAj.png)

Comment: Anychance there is a command in addition to the UI to make the snap private when publishing it to snap store?